# What events are available for Upstart?

Tags: upstart, events

Is there a list of available events that can be used for Upstart?

For example `start on local-filesystems` so *local-filesystems* is an event but when is it triggered and what other events are there?

Answer (score 32):

### Manpages

Starting in Ubuntu 11.04, there is an awesome man page created by James Hunt called `usptart-events` so from the terminal run:

```
man upstart-events
```

It is also available from the Ubuntu online manpages, [**upstart-events**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man7/upstart-events.7.html), but loses some formatting so a better online resource for the same information is from the Upstart [**cookbook**](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific).

### Visualisation of Jobs and Events

There is also an excellent tool, `initctl2dot` for visualization of upstart events. Below are examples of using the command to generate images from Ubuntu 12.04.

View all jobs:

```
initctl2dot -o - | dot -Tpng -o upstart.png
```

[image]

View only *plymouth*, *lightdm* and *mountall* jobs:

```
initctl2dot -r plymouth,lightdm,mountall -o - | dot -Tpng -o upstart2.png
```

[image]

[Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20120128192322/http://upstart.at/2011/03/25/visualisation-of-jobs-and-events-in-ubuntu-natty)

### Grep init

You can also `grep` for *emit* in the following directories:

```
grep -r emit /etc/init /etc/init.d /etc/network/if*.d
```

That will give you most of them, the others are emitted by the dbus bridge.

---

For more information and best practices,  see [The Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

Comment: The best way to view upstart-events(7) online is via the cookbook btw: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific (better formatting than manpages.ubuntu.com).

Answer (score 3):

These events are emited by either `upstart` itself or by `mountall` and all of them have their `man` pages:

> mounting mounted virtual-filesystems
>   local-filesystems all-swaps filesystem
>   remote-filesystems  started starting
>   stopping  stopped startup runlevel(7)

Any application can emit its own event, for example by

```
initctl emit suspend
```

Some of them you can see as the output of

```
grep emit /etc/init/*
```

More information also at:

http://netsplit.com/2008/04/27/upstart-05-events/

http://upstart.at/